# How can I get templateUrl in Component programmatically?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

If I have a AngularDart Component:

```dart
@Component(selector: "my-selector",useShadowDom: false,
    templateUrl: "packages/test/test.html")
class MyComponent {
     MyComponent() {
     ...
     }
     ...
 }
```

How can I get the templateUrl programmatically?
I want to avoid a constructor with an Element injected. An injected Injector would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```dart
@Component(selector: "my-selector", useShadowDom: false,
templateUrl: "packages/test/test.html")
class MyComponent {
    Injector _injector;

    MyComponent(this._injector) {
    }

    String get url {
        DirectiveMap _directiveMap = _injector.get(DirectiveMap);

        var tuples = _directiveMap['my-selector'];
        //Validate.isTrue(tuples[0].directive is Component);
        Component annotation = tuples[0].directive;
        //_logger.info("TemplateUrl: ${annotation.templateUrl}");

        return annotation.templateUrl;
    }
}
```